# Switch user in a .SQL for postgresql

Tags: postgresql, psql

Is it possible to do the following step in 1 .SQL file?

1. create a new role
2. login as the new role
3. alter role

Comment: In a `psql` script, yes. In an SQL script, no.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mean psql script. @LaurenzAlbe will you pls advise?

Comment: Where exactly in the process is your problem? Connectiong should be easy with `\c`.

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL, executing all those steps in one single .sql file, isn't directly possible due to how session authentication and role switching work. When you connect to a PostgreSQL database, you authenticate as a specific user for the duration of that connection. You can't change the authenticated user mid-session directly using standard SQL commands.